# syntax error before 'for'

Tags: c, function

i got error: "syntax error before 'for'" and I just don't understand why? Could you please explain why is that? I have few similar errors in code.

```
#define N 1024

 void Reverse_Binary( double *a, unsigned long Len);

int main()
   // here is error as well: error: syntax error before '{' token
{
 //here are different variables for all code

 buf = malloc(num_items*sizeof(double));

 //here are different functions

 Reverse_Binary(buf,N); 
}

void Reverse_Binary( double *a,unsigned long Len)  
{
    long x, xprim;
    int temp;

    for (x=0; x<Len; x++)
    {
         xprim= rev(x,N);   

         if (xprim > x)
         {
             temp = a[x];
             a[x] = a[xprim];
             a[xprim] = temp;s
         }
     }  
}
```

Comment: can you give the code before this point?  This body looks ok

Comment: What code comes before this method?

Comment: This compiles fine for me if I declare the missing symbols (N and rev)

Comment: the variable 'x' should not be integer?

Comment: Some stray macro might be involved. Are you sure there's no `temp` macro defined somewhere? Try renaming `temp` variable and see what happens.

Comment: just a little note, try to stick to variables in lower case for all of them. But the code you posted seems fine.

Comment: @Leniel Macaferi: What's that extra `s` doing there? You seem to have added it in your edit.

Comment: Is it wanted to swap  `double` variable using a `int` temp? That looks suspiciously wrong. If it is a feature, you should at least put a comment to explain.

Comment: run it through the preprocessor to see what the compiler sees. If you're using gcc do `gcc -E`

Comment: @AndreyT: sorry... while editing I typed that s... thanks for letting me know about it!

Answer (score 6):

You missed the main closing bracket.

Put a bracket after:

```
Reverse_Binary(buf,N);

} //that's the missing bracket
```

Also remove the last bracket after Reverse_Binary function.

Comment: +1: There's also a stray close brace after the function; I wonder if the intention was to use a (GCC extension) nested function...but then the `extern` declaration of the function was not appropriate.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: thanks. I didn't see it. I'll fix my answer

Comment: @0verbose yes, thanks. it was my mistake. but i still have the same error.

Comment: @andrey: please post the whole chunk of code with the change you did.

Comment: @0verbose I edited, but whole chunk of code is too big to post here.

Comment: @andrey: i suggest you to make some tries on your own. Try to comment big part of code until you are able to compile. Then start uncommenting little chunks of code in order to locate the problem. I can't tell you more.

Answer (score 2):

Check matching brackets first. When brackets go missing, compiler messages go seemingly awok because the code snippet looks right.

Comment: +1 for countering braindead downvote. As it is finally even the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks OK, so the only idea I have that you have maybe invisible CR characters. Some compilers on Unix/Linux do not like files edited on Windows/DOS which contains CR/LF (0x0d, 0x0a) instead of LF (0x0a) as line delimiters. 
Try editing your file with vi and it may show the supplemental CR as ^M characters at the end of the line.

Comment: Or a missing } in the previous (not shown) function.  When you are missing } or ) elements the parser can give some weird errors.

Comment: Could you explain the downvote please? The CR/LF is as good an explaination as anything. I know for sure that SUN's compiler on Solaris does not like them and that the error message it gives is not very useful in that sense.

Comment: There are unfortunately a number of people on here who appear to live out some passive-aggressive geek aggression in downvoting others as a hobby. I got downvoted in the past for pointing out that calloc works only for fixed size array entries. It's a shame as the level of knowledge on this forum is unequaled.

Comment: @tristopia does sun's compiler actually give a `syntax error before 'for'` for this code?  If the compiler misinterprets line endings, it would have shown up in the previous line as well.

Comment: I just checked, in fact it's not the compiler that does not like \r characters but the pre-processors, so you get a warning only on lines that start with a #. This said, I've got here some files that have mixed DOS and UNIX line ending, I have a collegue who is quite good at making this kind of shit.